# F# interactive, API restriction on dll referencing

Tags: f#, f#-interactive

How do you solve the error message that looks like this?

```
`Binding session to 'C:\Program Files (x86)\NLog\.NET Framework 4.0\NLog.dll'...

error FS0193: API restriction: The assembly 
'file:///C:\Program Files (x86)\NLog\.NET Framework 4.0\NLog.dll' has 
already loaded from a different location. It cannot be loaded from a 
new location within the same appdomain.
```

Code that triggers it, might look like this:

```
#r @"..\packages\NLog.2.0.0.2000\lib\net20\NLog.dll"
NLog.Config.SimpleConfigurator.ConfigureForConsoleLogging()
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It seems that FSI won't load from the given DLL other than by name, so this would sort the problem out:

```
#I @"..\packages\NLog.2.0.0.2000\lib\net20"
#r @"NLog.dll"
NLog.Config.SimpleConfigurator.ConfigureForConsoleLogging()
```

`#I` means to add that folder to the load-path

`#r` means to reference by dll-path; focusing on name. This means that FSI will use the file name first, looking in the system-wide search path and only then try to use the string after `#r` as a directory-relative hint.

So by doing it this way, you make the NLog load from your specified directory rather than a system-wide one.

Comment: I'm adding this answer here, because I couldn't find it while googling, reloading the interactive didn't help and I had to guess my way to the answer (which worked). So, google, here's some fodder.