# How to set up NLog in F# script (fsx)

Tags: logging, f#, console-application, nlog

i have some f# projects which use NLog for logging. 
And logging works fine when i use .exe produced by projects, i see output in files or console.

But now i need to use my types (which uses logging) defined in my project in fsx-script, and i got in trouble.

Part of my script

```
#r "NLog.dll"
#r "Emulators.dll" // contains some types which uses NLog
#r "DeviceEmulator.exe" // also contains types which uses NLog

// instantiating and run objects
```

All works fine but i does not see output from NLog neither in console nor in file. What have i missed?

Comment: Possible duplicate:[Using NLog with F# Interactive in Visual Studio - Need documentation](http://stackoverflow.com/q/14657954/1243762)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm currently have no access to computer to check, but likely your `NLog`cannot pick up its configuration, when being fired within a `fsi` script.

You may want finding `nlog.config` file within your compiled F# projects and copying it to the directory, where your `fsi.exe` (`FsiAnyCPU.exe` for 64-bit `fsi`) is located side by side with `Fsi.exe.config`(`FsiAnyCPU.exe.config`).

For F# 3.x on Windows the location is usually `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\F#\3.0\Framework\v4.0`.

Alternatively, you may switch to [configuring `NLog` from your code](https://github.com/nlog/NLog/wiki/Configuration-API) and run the configuration piece from your script.

Answer (score -1):

I dont know NLog, but may be you need to redirect the output.

```
Console.SetOut(someClassDerivingFromStringWriter)
Console.SetError(someClassDerivingFromStringWriter)
```